# Does Professor X have any responsibility for the state of the world?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

Throughout the course of *Logan*, it's obvious that Professor Xavier is having issues controlling his powers, and at the end of the movie, just before

> X-24 kills him

he claims to "remember" what he did and expresses regret. We also hear about an incident in Westchester that killed several mutants, that sounds like Xavier may have been involved. Is Xaiver the reason there are no more mutants? Is that why he's sorry, because he knows he killed them all?

Comment: Some info here: https://www.google.co.uk/amp/www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2017/03/logan-x-men-killed-westchester-incident-professor-x-where-are-the-mutants/amp

Comment: @cde should you want to defend your downvote, here http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2666/are-spoilers-a-reason-to-get-downvotes

Comment: @Lynob this site has a policy against spoilers in titles, because titles show up everywhere (main page, side bar, RSS feeds, etc). As a user, you're expected to have at least a passing familiarity with how the site works -- and to ask if you're not sure. Breaking those rules is undoubtedly going to get a negative reaction from other users.

Comment: @KutuluMike at least include it in the tour, which is supposed to introduce newbies to this site, and create a tag called spoilers.

Comment: Meta tags are bad, so, no, no tag called "spoilers" (which would ultimately be of no use anyway)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Xavier was the person who killed the 7 mutants that died *in the Westchester incident*. In-universe, the reporter described that event as being nearly identical to the accident at the hotel when Xavier has a seizure, so we're obviously supposed to piece together the connection. We don't *know* for sure who those 7 mutants were that died in Westchester, but Westchester County is where Xavier's School for Gifted Youngsters is located, and that's almost certainly not a coincidence. It seems reasonable that the incident resulted in the closing down of the school, at least, and possibly the X-Men.

However, Xavier isn't responsible for the death of *all* of the mutants. Xavier's seizure only killed those 7 unnamed mutants, after which he presumably went into hiding with Logan. Between the leader of the Reavers and the lead scientist from Alkali, we find out what happened to the rest. The Alkali group has been doping the food and drink supplies to suppress mutant births, and the Reavers have then been hunting down the mutants that weren't dying off on their own. Alkali's plan is to grow their own mutants through artificial insemination, and be the only ones that have such powered people.

Comment: No mention of water supplies being tainted. And nothing said the reavers were hunting mutants aside from the kids.

Comment: Also the radio was going to say the xmen before Logan turned it off.

Comment: When the Reavers capture Caliban one of them says to him "you used to track muties for us" or something similar. But you're right, it wasn't the "water" supply he was talking about, it was the soda/sports drink/etc supply (anything with corn syrup in it).

Answer (score 12):

No. Charles Xavier was sorry in that scene because he had just remembered the "Westchester incident", where one of his seizures hurt hundreds of people and even killed some. But the victims of that incident were (probably) random innocent people, not exclusively mutants, much less all the mutants in the world.

The mutants are gone because Zander Rice developed some method of preventing mutants from being born, as he explained to Wolverine himself near the very end of the movie.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I don't remember the movie actually mentioning a death toll for the Westchester incident, so the lack of citation on that might be why someone downvoted. I might have forgotten or overlooked where it was mentioned, but I do think adding that would improve this answer.